# Displaying water movement paths over grid in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing, climate, flood

I have an external .csv file with "From" cell, "To" cell, X, Y coordinates for the "From" cell, X Y coordinates for "To" cell and flow rate for water going from "From" cell to "to" cell. I can import this file in QGIS using Layer -> add Layer -> Add delimited text layer.

Each cell discharges water to one of its eight neighboring cells. My grid size is 80 x 80.

I would like to display water movement direction with an arrow for each cell.

Is there a way to do this in QGIS?

I do not want to use QGIS to determine the flow direction for me.

Comment: Edit your question and add a sample of the csv file as text. You also need to add a code attempt or your question is probably going to get closed

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `"FROM"` and `"TO"` fields are formatted like 'x, y', You can use a ["Geometry Generator"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/training_manual/basic_map/symbology.html#hard-fa-geometry-generator-symbology) symbol layer with the following expression:

```sql
make_line(                              -- make a line of the FROM and TO points
    make_point(                         -- make a point of the FROM x, y coordinates
        string_to_array("FROM")[0],     -- make an array of the FROM x, y coordinates and get the first element (x)
        string_to_array("FROM")[1]      -- make an array of the FROM x, y coordinates and get the second element (y)
    ),
    make_point(
        string_to_array("TO")[0],       -- make an array of the TO x, y coordinates and get the first element (x)
        string_to_array("TO")[1]        -- make an array of the TO x, y coordinates and get the second element (y)
    )
)
```

To create a Geometry Generator symbol layer:

[image]

You can then select the Arrow line type:

[image]

Maybe it's nice to alter the width of the arrow depending on the flow rate. In this case, use these buttons to configure the width of your arrows:

[image]

If the raw flow rate is not appropriate as a width, you can enter an expression as a function of your flow rate:

[image]

Result:

[image]

---

**References:**

- [Use QGIS expressions to create geometries: difference between geometry generator and geometry by expression](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/392618/use-qgis-expressions-to-create-geometries-difference-between-geometry-generator)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!